# How to use get_pages( ) correctly with 'child_of' to replace page with child page

Tags: plugin-development, pre-get-posts

I'm struggling to get the results I want here. After a couple hours of googling, I've decided to ask you all for help.

I'm trying to look at children of the current (queried) page, and if the page has a specific term within a specific taxonomy, show the child page content instead of the originally queried page. So, I've got the following:

```
function site_child($pid) {

    $site_term = io_multi_get_var('term', null);  //this is working properly from another function
    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $pid,
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'parent' => $pid,
    );
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages
    $children = get_pages($args);

    foreach ($children as $child) {

        if ( has_term($site_term,'site_assign',$child) ) {
            return $child->ID;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// modify the PAGE main query
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'replace_content_with_child' );
function replace_content_with_child( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_page() ) {

        if( $sitechild = site_child($query->query_vars['page_id']) ) {
            $query->query_vars['page_id'] = $sitechild;
        }
    }
}
```

This method actually works perfectly on the home page. The child page of "Home" is found, and the query is altered to show that page. However, I get no results when I try this on /about-us/mission/ for example (even though there is a child page that fits the conditions). If I var_dump($children), on the "Home" page, I get one result: the correct one. If I var_dump($children) on another page, I just get an array of ALL top level pages (and no children of anything). What am I doing wrong here? I've tried this without the 'parent' parameter AND without the 'child_of' parameter. I don't know if just haven't found the correct combination of parameters, or if there is a fundamental flaw in what I'm attempting...

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: If I var_dump($pid) on any page besides the home page, I receive "int(0)". I imagine this is the root of the problem. Something about `$query->query_vars['page_id']` is not yielding the actual ID of the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved this. I just needed to replace `$query->query_vars['page_id']` with `get_queried_object_id()` and everything works!

However, I just read Pieter's response and it appears that indeed, according to the codex, it's not supposed to work. Weird though, because it IS working. I guess we'll see if anything breaks...